# Using urldecode on a mysql_fetch_array Array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have been trying to convert the fields from a mysql_fetch_array (that are urlencoded) to urldecode before converting to JSON (json_encode)

Here's what I'm working with that doesn't work:The output is still urlencoded

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE tableId=$tableId";
$result = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($query));
foreach($result as $value) {
    $value = urldecode($value);
}
$jsonOut = array();
$jsonOut[] = $result;
echo (json_encode($jsonOut));
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah....!  you're not updating `$result` with the value returned by the function.  `$value` needs to be passed by reference.

```
foreach($result as &$value) {
    $value = urldecode($value);
}
```

or

```
foreach($result as $i => $value) {
    $result[$i] = urldecode($value);
}
```

when you do this...

```
foreach($result as $value) {
    $value = urldecode($value);
}
```

The result of the function is lost at at iteration of the `foreach`.  You're trying to update each value stored in `$result` but that's not happening.

- Also take note that the code only fetches one row from your query.  I'm not sure if that's by design or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE tableId=$tableId";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$value = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
$value[] = urldecode($row);
}
$jsonOut = array();
$jsonOut[] = $result;
echo (json_encode($jsonOut));
```